# Sidebar not positioned properly despite CSS

Tags: html, css

I run [a blog](http://demo.catastropherising.com) and I was making a new layout for it when I ran into some trouble with the sidebar.

I've tried everything as far as moving the sidebar above the content, changing the position, etc., but to no avail.

```css
body #sidebar {
    width: 25%;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;    
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>

<div id="sidebar"> 
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

I feel like it's gotta be something small. What am I missing?

Comment: change the order, first the sidebar, then the main div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** The reason why your code was not working is that the ***p***
 tag is a block level element. Thus it was occupying the entire width of the screen. (Here red is #main and black is #sidebar)

[image]

Also the **#sidebar** came after your **#main**. Because of these two reasons, your **float: left** was not working the way you were expecting it to.
This is why you have two ways of solving the problem. You either write **#sidebar** before **#main** or you specify **display: inline-block** in your **#main**.

[image]

Adding a display: inline-block causes the elements to take up only the amount of space required.

Here's the code

```css
  body #sidebar {
    width: 25%;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
}

#main{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id = "main">
<p>Main</p>
</div>

<div id = "sidebar"> 
<p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I did this and it solved the problem. I had to keep to the sidebar below the content so that it would display that way on mobile platforms. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Happy to help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your sidebar should be the first and then your div, or use this snippet:

```
#main {
    width:75%;
    float: right;
}

#sidebar {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code.
HTML

```
<body>
<div class="Section">
<div id="sidebar"> 
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>
<div id="main">
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>


</div>

</body>
```

CSS

```
#Section{

  width:100%;

}
#main{

  width:75%;
  float:right;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the quick fix, but i am not sure why you are going through huge page of re inventing the wheel.

Are you aware of  https://getbootstrap.com  and  https://startbootstrap.com/ and i think this page already https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-portfolio-item/ have what your are looking for. Look up their licence and use it.

By the way i took the below code from your page source code

```
body #sidebar {
    background-color: #fff;
    /*padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;*/

    border: 1px solid #975FB4;
    width:25%;
    float:left;

    }


body #main {
    /*margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;*/
    padding:10px;
    height: auto;
      width: 75%;
}

<div id = "sidebar"> 
<p>Some text</p>
</div>

<div id = "main">
<p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider nesting your divs within a "wrapper". It's good for consistency and keeping all of your divs where they're supposed to go. Using display inline block and reordering your divs will do what you need, but really having a clear structure for your html and css will save you loads of headaches in the future.

I did a quick example of what I think is more what your trying to achieve based on your link. https://codepen.io/morganfens/pen/gxaQVJ

HTML

```
<div id="sidebar"> 
    <p>I'm a sidebar</p>
</div>

<div id="main">
    <p>Main Content Goes Here</p>
</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#sidebar {
    width: 25%;
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}

#main{
  display:inline-block;
  padding-top:15px;
  padding-bottom:15px;
  width:70%;
  text-align: left;
}
```